# getFinalPrice returns 0.00 for some configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

In a Magento 2.2.6 installation we have the following configurable product for example:

[image: products]

The product with ID 3502 has the products with IDs 3503 and 3504 as its configurable options. All products have a price assigned.

However, when I load a product collection via

```
$products = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                 ->addWebsiteFilter($store->getWebsiteId())
                 ->setStore($store)
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

and then iterate over the collection and use

```
$product->getFinalPrice();
```

the function always resturns `0.00` for the product with ID `3502` - it should be `261.84` of course.

It **does** work for other configurable products, but not for some. So far I have no clue why it would not work for this particular product for instance.

I also checked the flat tables and made sure they are properly indexed.

May be someone has any pointers on why Magento could possibly return `0.00` for these products for their "final price".

Comment: check the price value in particular store.. I believe in that store it should be 0.00

Comment: Good point, but I have checked that too. The prices are not overridden for the particular store. Only the 'default config' is used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by an inconsistency in the database. As you can see in the screenshot, the base product displayed a price - but there shouldn't be any price displayed there for a configurable product. After editing and saving the configurable product again, everything worked.

The data for these products was migrated from a Magento 1.x installation. As far as I know, in Magento 1.x you had to set a price for the base product and the configured products only added to that price. I assume that during migration the price for the base product wasn't properly reset.

Comment: Oh yeah... Make sure you cleanup the prices and special prices and msrp and any other price type attribtues directly linked to the configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `addPriceData` on the collection:

```
$products = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
             ->addWebsiteFilter($store->getWebsiteId())
             ->setStore($store)
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addPriceData();
```